# Use mat-button-toggle-group inside a mat-grid

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular5, angular-material-5

I have 5 buttons occupying 5 columns of a `mat-grid`. The buttons should behave as toggle buttons and all 5 should belong to a single group.
I tried enclosing the `mat-grid` with `mat-button-toggle-group`, but still isn't working.
Any help is much appreciated.

Code :

```
 <mat-grid-list cols="11" rowHeight="40px">  
   <mat-grid-tile >
      <label>Label 1</label><!-- below buttons should be a single group -->
   </mat-grid-tile>
   <mat-grid-tile colspan='2'>
          <mat-button-toggle >Button 1</mat-button-toggle>

    </mat-grid-tile>
      ....
     <mat-grid-tile colspan='2'>
          <mat-button-toggle >Button 5</mat-button-toggle>
     </mat-gri-tile>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DOM structure of the grid is getting in the way of the toggle group. You can get around that by adding the group as a standalone element, and assigning the group to each button in your controller.  For example:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="3">
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-button-toggle value="bold">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-button-toggle value="italic">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-button-toggle value="underline">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
<mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style">
</mat-button-toggle-group>


import { Component, ViewChild, ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonToggle, MatButtonToggleGroup } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'button-toggle-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'button-toggle-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['button-toggle-overview-example.css'],
})
export class ButtonToggleOverviewExample {
  @ViewChild(MatButtonToggleGroup) group: MatButtonToggleGroup;
  @ViewChildren(MatButtonToggle) toggles: QueryList<MatButtonToggle>;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.toggles.forEach(toggle => toggle.buttonToggleGroup = this.group);
    });
  }
}
```

A stackblitz example is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nkkqx9?embed=1&file=app/button-toggle-overview-example.html).